# VBA Run-Time Error '438' Changing a cells value using wb.ws.range

Tags: excel, vba

My issue involves 
My is simply why can't I simplify my code using wb.ws.range("C6").value = to something** to change a value. 
I keep getting error code 438.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

```
private sub reset_input_sheet()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets("CDR_Input")

'perf treatment type
wb.ws.Range("C6").value = "Multi-Stage Fracture"



end sub
```

Comment: You could use `ws.Range("C6").value = "Multi-Stage Fracture"` instead of the last line, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you need this. You don't need to reference the workbook once the sheet variable includes a reference.

```
Private Sub reset_input_sheet()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("CDR_Input")

'perf treatment type
ws.Range("C6").Value = "Multi-Stage Fracture"

End Sub
```